# Error with include router in underscore backbone

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Trying to use underscore in project with backbone, but receive an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

In my view, because variable Router undefined. I am new one in backbone and underscore, so please help me, maby something need to change in my code.

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-2.1.1',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        view: 'view/view'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require([
    'app'
], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

**app.js**

```
define([
    'router' // Request router.js
], function(Router) {

    var initialize = function() {
        Router.initialize();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

**router.js**

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'model/model',
    'view'
], function(Backbone, appState) {

    var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "":         "selected_currency",
            "!/":       "selected_currency",
            "!/finish": "finish"
        },

        selected_currency: function() {
            appState.set({state: "selected_currency"});
        },

        finish: function () {
            appState.set({state: "finish"});
        }
    });

    Backbone.history.start();

    return router;
});
```

**/model/model.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var AppState = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            currencies:         ['USD', 'EUR'],
            selected_currency:  '',
            state:              "selected_currency"
        },

        url: '/site/create-account'
    });

    return new AppState();
});
```

**view/view.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router', // Request router.js
    'model/model'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router, appState) {

    var Block = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#block"),

        templates: {
            "selected_currency": _.template($('#step_1').html()),
            "finish": _.template($('#step_1_complete').html() + $('#step_2').html())
        },

        events: {
            "click button": "get_currency"
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        },

        get_currency: function() {
            var currency = this.$el.find("[name=currency]").val();

            appState.set({selected_currency: currency});

            appState.fetch({
                data: {'currency': appState.get('selected_currency')},
                type: 'POST'
            });

            appState.once('sync error', function(model) {
                this.model.set({"state": "finish"});
            }, this);
        },

        render: function() {
            var state = this.model.get("state");
            $(this.el).html(this.templates[state](this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    new Block({model: appState});

    var router = new Router();
    appState.trigger("change");

    appState.bind("change:state", function() {
        var state = this.get("state");
        if (state == "selected_currency")
            router.navigate("!/", false);
        else
            router.navigate("!/" + state, false);
    });
});
```

Comment: circular deps may cause, view in deps of router, router in deps of view. Try to remove 'router' from view deps and add following in line you instance router - `var router; require(['router'], function(R){ router = new R(); })`

Comment: Maby I need to include view not in router? Maby in another place?

Comment: as i can see there in no sense to include view in router deps, you dont use it inside router

Comment: Where better to include it?

Comment: where u will use it :)

Comment: =) I need it in main page index.html

Comment: ok, then put it in app.js deps array